# Apache conf setup to serve subdomain site alongside OwnCloud deploy

Tags: apache, vhosts, owncloud

I have deployed OwnCloud 8 on a Ubuntu 14.04 instance to the domain `box.example.com`. I would like to host some static html on the same VM and have apache point `project.example.com` to it at `/var/www/html`.

In apache the file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/owncloud.conf` was created by OwnCloud containing:

```
#I changed the first line as follows
##Alias /owncloud "/var/www/owncloud/" # commented out
Alias / "/var/www/owncloud/"
<Directory "/var/www/owncloud">
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
      Dav off
    </IfModule>

    SetEnv HOME /var/www/owncloud
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/owncloud
</Directory>
```

How can I add a new subdomain VM in apache so that I'll have two working sites: `box.example.com` (OwnCloud instance) and `project.example.com` (static html). So far with everything I have tried `project` loads the OwnCloud front-end and does not open the static html.

Do I need to touch `/etc/hosts`?

I will update with examples of things I am trying and outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add both virtualhost in the same file (after the first ) directive or create another file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ . You can start from the existing default file and adapt the servername and directory where your "project" is, and any other directive as needed.

Beware, if you run Apache2.4, the files should be named anyname.conf, for instance box.example.com.conf

And don't forgot to reload your apache server after having enabled the site.

You also need to set-up your DNS, in a zone file, for both box.example.com and project.example.com to point to the IP of your server.

Answer (score 0):

You could create virtual host config files like `/etc/apache/sites-available/01-owncloud`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName box.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud

    <Directory /var/www/owncloud/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/owncloud-error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/owncloud-access.log combined

    Redirect 301 /.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav
    Redirect 301 /.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav
</VirtualHost>
```

Then enable it with `a2ensite 01-owncloud`.
Don't forget to set `NameVirtualHost *:80` somewhere in a conf. I used `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`.